# Cannot access folders

Tags: windows-8

I cannot access any of the folders of the windows from my ubuntu. What should I do? It tells me that no windows should not be in "hibernate" mode and to completely shut down my windows. I did it several times but nothing worked.

Comment: Try running chkdisk from Windows.